# Batch file to delete all folders in a directory except the newest folder

Tags: batch-file, backup, directory

I am trying to delete old backups in a specific folder after a new backup has been done. As i do not really have experience with DOS commands i mashed a couple of scripts i found on the internet into one:

```
::(C)2008 "BuckFix" www.winsupportforum.de
@echo off
setlocal

set workdir="M:\BACKUPS\CACHE_SSD\"
set folder=
:: get list of all folders, oldest first
dir %workdir% /AD /B /t:w /OD > %temp%folder.tmp
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%i in (%temp%folder.tmp) do set "folder=%%i"
del %temp%folder.tmp

::checking if its the right one...just for debugging
echo newest... %folder%

set filedir="M:\BACKUPS\CACHE_SSD\%folder%"

::delete all folders except %folder% ...but how?

pause
```

So picking the newest folder works fine but i don't know how to delete all folders except that one. I think it'll just be a simple for-loop but all my attempts failed so far.
It has to be a safe method as it is a backup folder and i just want to keep the most recent backup. I had delete scripts that worked but when there was only one folder it deleted that one as well. And when the directory was empty it killed the whole directory.

Comment: Managed to get it working with this attempt: `pushd "%filedir%" && rd /s /q "%workdir%" 2>nul` do you think this is a good option?

Comment: in fact it is a clever workaround

Comment: Trouble is, it deletes the subfolders as well. So if i have the newest folder and there are two subfolders in it, it deletes both subfolders but not the main folder. I need it to keep the content of the folder... do you know how i can modify it so that it keeps all the subfolders in the newest folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "workdir=M:\BACKUPS\CACHE_SSD\"
set "folder="
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir %workdir% /AD /B /TW /O-D') do (
    set "folder=%%~fi"
    goto :break
)
:break
echo newest... %folder%

for /f "skip=1 tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir %workdir% /AD /B /TW /O-D') do   (
    echo rd /s /q "%%~fi"
)

pause
```

Test this.Actual removing command is echoed .Delete echo in `echo rd /s /q "%%~fi"` if everything is ok.

Comment: Thanks! But that deletes the newest folders and keeps the oldest, weirdly.

Comment: @Malte - fixed! Check it now.

Comment: Thats working! But it uses the wrong directory in `echo rd /s /q "%%~fi"` it uses _M:\BACKUPS\-foldername-_ instead of _M:\BACKUPS\CACHE_SSD\-foldername-_.

Comment: @Malte - the %folder% is correct change it in the second loop.

Comment: Hang on, where should i replace it? Because `echo %folder%` prints M:\BACKUPS\foldername. Where can i change that?

Comment: @Malte - here - `for /f "skip=1 tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir %workdir% /AD /B /TW /O-D')`  - the second FOR call...You can change the workdir with something else.