# Deleting all but the newest folder using a batch script

Tags: loops, batch-file

I am trying to delete all but the newest folder using a batch script.

A similar question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828746/batch-file-to-delete-all-folders-in-a-directory-except-the-newest-folder), so I tried using that as a template and things are getting screwed up.

The folder that I need to purge of all but the newest folder is actually a folder containing backups. In another script, I am backing up the folder that contains this folder, which also includes the folder that this is a backup.

**H:\LOS** is the folder being backed up.

**H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy** is the folder that contains backups of **H:\LOS\Default** that are taken everyday.

I want to backup **H:\LOS**, but I don't need any of the folders in **DefaultChromeCopy** since I'm already backing up Default. I will be running this weekly, so I want to temporarily move the newest folder in the **DefaultChromeCopy** directory to **T:\Backups** for safe keeping, then delete all the folders in **DefaultChromeCopy**, and then backup **H:\LOS**. That backup will also go to **T:\Backups**, and then I can move the folder that was the newest folder in **DefaultChromeCopy** back to its original location.

So in the end, I will have a backup of **H:\LOS** with an empty DefaultChromeCopy folder, and all the folders in **H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy** will have been deleted except for the newest one (which was "moved" temporarily).

So, using the code from the other SO answer as a starting put, I have this (without the asterisks around the echo):

```
if not exist "T:\Backups" md "T:\Backups"
set "workdir=H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy"
set "folder="
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir %workdir% /AD /B /TW /O-D') do (
    set "folder=%%~fi"
    **echo** robocopy H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy\%folder% T:\Backups\%folder% /e /w:0 /r:2
    goto :break
)
:break
echo newest... %folder%
for /f "skip=1 tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir %workdir% /AD /B /TW /O-D') do   (
    echo rd /s /q "%%~fi"
)
```

I've set up a dummy drive H and dummy drive T and modeled the folders in order to test this out.

[image]

You can see that **ne** is the newest folder.

With the echo denoted by asterisks, I get:

```
newest... H:\ne
rd /s /q "H:\sdf"
rd /s /q "H:\6"
rd /s /q "H:\5"
rd /s /q "H:\4"
rd /s /q "H:\3"
rd /s /q "H:\2"
rd /s /q "H:\1"
```

The path for "newest" used to be right but now even that is not right.

I've stopped here, because so much is going wrong already. How can I fix the paths? Also, if I run without the echo, ALL the folders in DefaultChromeCopy (or sometimes, even stranger, all of them except ne and sdf) get copied to **T:\Backups**, which is not what is supposed to happen. Only the newest folder is supposed to get copied.

Here is the part that will actually do the "backup", and then move `%folder%` back where it came from (`%folder%` is the newest folder from DefaultChromeCopy).

```
robocopy "H:\LOS\" "T:\Backups\LOS_Backup_%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%_%TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%" /e /w:0 /r:2
robocopy T:\Backups\%folder% H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy /e /w:0 /r:2
start "" "T:\Backups"
```

*The directories in DefaultChromeCopy are not modified after they are created, so Date Created and Date Modified should be the same. I only want to keep the newest folder in DefaultChromeCopy, by moving it to T:\Backups so I can delete all the folders in DefaultChromeCopy for the backup (I don't need even the newest backup in the big backup I'm taking). Hope this all makes sense...*

**UPDATE:**

Running:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "workdir=H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy"
set "folder="
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir %workdir% /AD /B /TW /O-D') do (
    set "folder=%%~fi"
    echo %%~fi
    echo robocopy %%~fi T:\Backups\!folder! /e /w:0 /r:2
    goto :break
)
:break
echo newest... !folder!
for /f "skip=1 tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir %workdir% /AD /B /TW /O-D') do   (
    echo rd /s /q "%workdir%\%%~i"
)
```

produces:

```
H:\ne
robocopy H:\ne T:\Backups\H:\ne /e /w:0 /r:2
newest... H:\ne
rd /s /q "H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy\sdf"
rd /s /q "H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy\6"
rd /s /q "H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy\5"
rd /s /q "H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy\4"
rd /s /q "H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy\3"
rd /s /q "H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy\2"
rd /s /q "H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy\1"
```

So it looks like the directories that are supposed to be deleted are getting deleted, but the "newest" part is still a little wonky. **I need to figure out how to get "H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy\ne". Right now:**

```
%%~fi --> H:\ne
%workdir%\%%~fi --> H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy\H:\ne
T:\Backups\!folder! --> T:\Backups\H:\ne
T:\Backups\%folder% --> T:\Backups\
?????????????!!!!! --> H:\LOS\Default\ChromeCopy\ne & T:\Backups\ne
```

Fortunately, I found a sort of a workaround. There should only be 1 folder left in DefaultChromeCopy, so even though I can't figure out how to reference it, I can reference its parent. Thus, running the following deletes all but the newest folder from DefaultChromeCopy, backs DefaultChromeCopy up to T:\Backups, deletes everything in DefaultChromeCopy, backs up H:\LOS to T:\Backups, then copies DefaultChromeCopy back to H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy and deletes it from T:\Backups.

Here is the final working script. Thanks for everyone's help:

```
@echo off
echo Beginning LOS backup - deleting all Chrome backups except the newest one
if not exist "T:\Backups" md "T:\Backups"
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "chromebackups=H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy"
set "folder="
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir %chromebackups% /AD /B /TW /O-D') do (
    set "folder=%%~fi"
    echo folder is !folder!
    goto :deleteolds
)
:deleteolds
for /f "skip=1 tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir %chromebackups% /AD /B /TW /O-D') do   (
    rd /s /q "%chromebackups%\%%~i"
)
robocopy "H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy" "T:\Backups\DefaultChromeCopy" /e /w:0 /r:2
set topurge="H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy"
cd /d %topurge%
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
robocopy "H:\LOS" "T:\Backups\LOS_Backup_%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%_%TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%" /e /w:0 /r:2
robocopy "T:\Backups\DefaultChromeCopy" "H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy" /e /w:0 /r:2
rmdir "T:\Backups\DefaultChromeCopy" /s /q
start "" "T:\Backups"
echo LOS Backup has completed! You can now ZIP the folder in T:\Backups\, upload that to the LOS Repository server, and then delete T:\Backups manually.
```

Comment: So, do you want to keep the directory which was was most recently created, the directory which most recently changed, the directory which houses the file or directory which was most recently modified, or the directory which houses the file or directory which was most recently created?

Comment: The date modified is later than the date created, a directory has to be created before it can accept content. If you look at your own screen shot you'll see it!

Comment: Your FOR variable does not contain the path to your Working Directory which is why the `echo rd` output does not look correct.  In your first FOR command you need to use delayed expansion with the %folder% variable.

Comment: @Compo Okay, but sorting newest to oldest by date modified and date created will produce the same exact list, since folders are only created there once per day.

Comment: @InterLinked, when using delayed expansion you need to reference your variables with exclamation points when inside a parenthesized code block. `!folder!`

Comment: @InterLinked, run this code at the cmd prompt from the root of your H: drive.. `dir H:\LOS\DefaultChromeCopy /AD /B /TW /O-D`. Your output will not have the path in the output. The FOR command can only capture the root folder name.  So your `RD` command needs to look like this: `rd /s /q "%workingDir%\%%~i"`